# Expand the following dictionary into following list

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, superpermutation

how to generate the following list from the following dictionary

```
d = {2: 4, 3: 1, 5: 3}

f = [
    2**1,2**2, 2**3, 2**4, 3**1, 5**1, 5**2, 5**3, 
    2**1 * 3, 2**2 * 3, 2**3 * 3, 2**4 * 3, 5**1 * 3, 5**2 * 3, 5**3 * 3, 
    2**1 * 5, 2**2 * 5, 2**3 * 5, 2**4 * 5, 
    2**1 * 5**2, 2**2 * 5**2, 2**3 * 5**2, 2**4 * 5**2, 3**1 * 5**2, 
    2**1 * 5**3, 2**2 * 5**3, 2**3 * 5**3, 2**4 * 5**3, 3**1 * 5**3, 
    2**1 * 3**1 * 5**1, 2**1 * 3**1 * 5**2, 2**1 * 3**1 * 5**3, 
    2**2 * 3**1 * 5**1, 2**2 * 3**1 * 5**2, 2**2 * 3**1 * 5**3, 
    2**3 * 3**1 * 5**1, 2**3 * 3**1 * 5**2, 2**3 * 3**1 * 5**3, 
    2**4 * 3**1 * 5**1, 2**4 * 3**1 * 5**2, 2**4 * 3**1 * 5**3, 
    ]
```

Moreover I want to expand for more general case ie dictionary of k key-value pairs

Edit:
Explanation of the pattern: Each key is raised to power of 0 to it's value and after that for each of those terms we do combination with similar terms from other keys.

I can think of doing so in recursive ways. Any non recusive approach is welcome.

PS: Order is not important

Comment: Can you explain the pattern? See how to create a [mcve]. What's preventing you from solving the problem yourself? Edit the question.

Comment: Why does the list contain both `5**1 * 3` and `3**1 * 5`? That's the same number.

Comment: @KellyBundy sorry my bad fixed it. but duplicate generation in not much of a concern for me, we can anytime dedup if necessary.

Answer (score 6):

One way, expanding the list with each possible factor and its powers:

```
f = [1]
for k, v in d.items():
    f += [x * k**i
          for x in f 
          for i in range(1, v+1)]
```

Perhaps faster, repeatedly multiplying with the factor instead of computing powers:

```
f = [1]
for k, v in d.items():
    g = f
    for _ in range(v):
        g = [x * k for x in g]
        f += g
```

Somewhat tricky version of that which is short and I believe fast (confirmed by OP in the comments):

```
from itertools import islice, repeat
from operator import mul

f = [1]
for k, v in d.items():
    f += map(mul, repeat(k, len(f) * v), f)
```

A completely different way, first computing the powers for each factor and then using `itertools.product` and `math.prod` to combine them:

```
from itertools import product, accumulate, repeat
from math import prod

f = list(map(prod, product(*[[k**i for i in range(v+1)]
                             for k, v in d.items()])))
```

All include the number `1` in the list. If that's a problem, just remove it.

Comment: awesome . thanks a lot . you should mention , last one works on python 3.8+.

Comment: @BobMcCheese Meh, 3.8 is over 2.5 years old by now, so I don't feel like pointing that out anymore :-)

Comment: 3rd one is the winner in speed. Here are the time for some larger v,` 7.25
2.80
2.08
6.45`

Comment: @BobMcCheese Thanks for measuring. Looks like what I suspected (though I really couldn't tell where the last one would fall, as it's so different).